# Infinity while loop gets only one result

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I'm writing a P2P program, which has to send and receive data betweed multiple instances of it. 
I'm facing with a problem when I created separate thread for listening for incoming data in infinity while loop, but I only get first message, and then nothing else. 
What am I doing wrong?
Code:

```
Task t = new Task(() => {
                try {
                    server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(STD_IP), STD_PORT);
                    server.Start();
                    odjemalec = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    nwStream = odjemalec.GetStream();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                }
                while(true) {
                    listen();
                }


            });
            t.Start();
```

Comment: you should have 2 threads ... one accepting and one for reading ... also each reaeding thread should have own client reference ... not mention that your Task usage is wrong here ... and one more comment: why don't you use async api of TcpListener at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Tasks (and I highly recommend that approach) the you need a **Listener Task** and a **TcpClient Responder Task** for each incoming connection.

**Here's a basic TCP Listener Task**

```
static async Task StartTcpServerAsync()
{
    var tcpListener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999));
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        _ = StartTcpClientAsync(tcpClient);
    }
}
```

We initalise the `TcpListener` and start listening for connections.  Everytime we get a connection, we hand the associated `TcpClient` off to a new Task.

**Here's a Server side TCP Client Task** - This lives on the server, it's started by the listener

```
static async Task StartTcpClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection from: [{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}]");

    var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    var buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (true)
    {
        int x = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint}] _ " +
            $"read {x} bytes {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)}");
    }
}
```

In this example we just write out the byte received.

**Finally**

For completeness here's a Main and also a TCPSender - usually the Sender will be on a completely different computer, but to show the power of Tasks, we'll run it from the same process.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    _ = StartTcpServerAsync();
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    await RunSenderAsync();
}
static async Task RunSenderAsync()
{
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 9999);
    var s = tcpClient.GetStream();
    tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
    for (var i = 65; i < 91; i++)
    {
        s.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), 0, 1);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

A place I find a lot of people get confused, is that you need a TcpClient on the server for each connection you receive.

Comment: This will not working as you are not awaiting `StartTcpClientAsync` so `stream.ReadAsync` is not awaited too

Comment: `stream.ReadAsync` doesn't create thread ... it works on system inerrupts and without await it's not working ... it is different from `Task.Run` .. also `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)` is wrong ... it should be `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, x)`

Comment: Hi @Selvin ``StartTcpClientAsync`` is not awaited.  If it was awaited then we would never see any new connections until the "StartTcpClientAsync" finished which would only happen when the first client disconnected.  Because this is running from a Console App there is no syncronisation context.

Comment: i've checked (copy the code and compile) ...it's not working - it's only accept as expected and doesn't read (also as expected)

Comment: The fix is to replace `_ = StartTcpClientAsync(tcpClient);` with `Task.Run(async () => await _ = StartTcpClientAsync(tcpClient));`

Comment: @Selvin , please see my next answer so you can see this working.

Comment: @Selvin StartTcpServerAsync() runs syncronously on the Main Thread up until the first await() at which point in time the Main() continues on the Main Thread.  When the first connection comes in, the await in ``StartTcpServerAsync()`` continues on a Worker Thread, this worker thread then calls the ``await StreamReader`` because this is a console application there is no ``syncronisation context`` and so the default action is for the await's continue on Worker Threads when they return.